# Is it bad to start a sentence with a citation

Tags: numbers, citation

e.g.   [14,6] give 3 and 2.4-approximations for the FVS problem.

Also when do you not use numbers from one to ten as worded.

e.g.  The earliest algorithms had an approximation factor of 16, later algorithms improved the approximation factor to ten, 9.5, eight, 6.5 and three respectively.

The cited questions is about why my 2nd question is about the convention and whether or not it applies to a continuous quantity when it takes discrete values 
e.g. does the rule apply to continuous variables e.g. The height of the ball is maximized at time 2e, four, 4.4,3, 2\pi, 2.5e, eight, 3e, 3 \pi and nine

and yes [14,6] are references listed in my bibliography I've found numbered bibliographies to be quite common but I'm not sure where it is okay to start the sentence with a citation.

Comment: What are 14 and 6?  If they're references to citations in a bibliography, it's better to use the author's name and end the sentence with the citation.

Comment: In scientific papers one usually mentions the author's name first as in  "Ellestad et al²³ have found that zinc can increase the..."  or you can quote their conclusion ""According to Ellestad and co-workers²³, "if you add zinc to the mixture...""

Comment: Some citation methods use numbers like this ... [7] ... where that is the 7th item in the bibliography.  So, in your comments, do not assume your method is better than this one in all situations.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth   my question is on the rule not on why it exists 

e.g. does the rule apply to continuous variables e.g.  The height of the ball is maximized at time 2e, four, 4.4,3, 2\pi, 2.5e, eight, 3e, 3 \pi and nine.

Comment: You need to ask your tutor etc to point you to the style guide they require you to use (if they haven't already done so). This is obviously in a different domain from standard everyday English; it is covered by conventions (perhaps differing from establishment to establishment) rather than rules of general English.

Comment: Since the duplicate question doesn't answer your first question: yes it's bad to start with a number or symbol; in English sentences are started with a word so they can be capitalized.